# How can I filter out spells that use attack roll on D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cleric, attack-roll, dnd-beyond

I play a Cleric and plan to take the [Elven Accuracy](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/elven-accuracy) feat. Thus, my spells that use attack rolls would be greatly improved. But how do I find them? Is setting the Attack Type in the advanced filter the only way? The results show only 5 spells; I find it disappointing to think that's all there is, but if that's the case then I want to know, and not to look for something I haven't actually lost.

[image: Image of an "Attack" filter]

Comment: Don't be too disappointed by the number of spells before you consider their utility, and remember the fable of [The Cat & the Fox](http://read.gov/aesop/120.html).  It is likely that you are going to be 'spamming' these spells anyway, and their solid interaction with _Elven Accuracy_ is great.  Both _guiding bolt_ and _inflict wounds_ have great damage output and scale with slot level, and _spiritual weapon_ gives you an extra attack each round; you will likely be using these for most of your level 1-4 slots.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### There are only six cleric spells that call for an attack roll, though three subclasses have more.

I’ve manually reviewed the entire cleric spell list; the list of five spells listed in D&D Beyond with the filters for melee and ranged attacks is missing one:

- [*guiding bolt*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/guiding-bolt) (ranged)
- [*inflict wounds*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/inflict-wounds) (melee)
- [*spiritual weapon*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/spiritual-weapon) (melee)
- [*contagion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/contagion) (melee)
- [*dispel evil and good*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-evil-and-good) (melee)
- [***plane shift***](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/plane-shift) (melee, to banish an unwilling creature to the specified plane)

However, some cleric domains get more in addition to this list from their domain spells. For example, the Death Domain gets three more attack spells:

- [*ray of sickness*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ray-of-sickness) (ranged)
- [*ray of enfeeblement*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/ray-of-enfeeblement) (ranged)
- [*vampiric touch*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/vampiric-touch) (melee)

Here is the quick summary of which subclasses get additional attack roll spells:

| Cleric Domain | Additional Attack Spells |
| --- | --- |
| [Death](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#DeathDomain) | 3 |
| [Grave](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#GraveDomain) | 2 |
| [Light](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/cleric#LightDomain) | 1 |

[Kirt](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/23547/kirt) provided a helpful comment on your question that I think gives a good perspective on your situation here:

> Don't be too disappointed by the number of spells before you consider their utility, and remember the fable of [The Cat & the Fox](http://read.gov/aesop/120.html). It is likely that you are going to be 'spamming' these spells anyway, and their solid interaction with Elven Accuracy is great. Both *guiding bolt* and *inflict wounds* have great damage output and scale with slot level, and *spiritual weapon* gives you an extra attack each round; you will likely be using these for most of your level 1-4 slots.

Comment: Now I only wish for an attack roll cantrip for my cleric, but I guess that would be a bit too much. Well, crossbow and rapier it is.

Comment: @Mołot Talk to your DM about swapping in a spell or two from another spell list. I've discussed this several times, see [these answers](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=changing+spell+lists+user%3A62294) of mine for some guidance.

Comment: @Mołot What is the flavor of your cleric?  If their elfyness is more important than their Domain, you might try to persuade your DM that the cantrip _Green Flame Blade_ should be available to you, _per_ Thomas Markov's suggestion.

Comment: @Kirt If they're playing a High Elf, it already is. Don't forget that racial ability score bonuses can be freely reassigned now, thanks to the rules in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything, so High Elf Clerucs are entirely feasible now.

Comment: Also, an Arcana Cleric can get up to 6 additional attack spells, 2 cantrips and one spell each of 6th-9th levels.

Comment: @nick012000 I was indeed forgetting that high elves get a wizard spell cantrip.  However, it may be that the OP is not playing a High Elf, given that they said "Now I only wish for an attack roll cantrip for my cleric, but I guess that would be a bit too much"

Comment: @nick012000 The two cantrips for an Arcane cleric are indeed a possibility as well, however I don't think the spells of 6-9 will be relevant to the OP if they have to wait until 17th level to get the first one.  Since Thomas Markov has not included Arcana clerics in his answer, though, I encourage you to write a competing answer focusing on them.

Comment: @Kirt My second comment was directed at Thomas Markov as a way for him to improve his own answer, since suggesting ways for an answer to be improved is one of the primary intended functions of the comment section.